# Will Microsoft Lync run on Windows Azure Virtual Machine roles?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, lync, azure-vm-role

Will Microsoft Lync run on Windows Azure Virtual Machine roles running Windows?  [Azure now supports persistent virtual machines](http://redmondmag.com/articles/2012/06/07/windows-azure-to-gain-iaas-linux-hybrid-cloud-support.aspx).

Comment: Are 'does this program work on this operating system/environment' considered programming questions?

Answer (score 0):

Lync on Windows Azure Virtual Machine is currently not supported.

Comment: Is it not officially supported or is it just not technically feasible?

Comment: The reason is both. During preview phase Lync was not in the list as supported product to get it working with Windows Azure Virtual Machines. In future things may change.

Comment: If Microsoft is listening, the reason we want Lync on Azure VMs is that we want to use cloud based services to the extent possible but your own service offering of Office 365 for hosted Lync does not let 3rd party tools developed using your APIs (UCMA etc) to connect to Office 365.  Now that you dont even support Lync on VM instances on your own cloud which would have enabled this access, you are leaving your loyal UC developers in the lurch.